# Excel - Moving rows based on column values

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with 200k records with Debit/Credit values, but not arranged.
I want to rearrange the complete rows (but not values because of several other columns)  i.e. First the debit row then the credit row with (-)ve value.

Below image shows Current and Required data format:
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i78U.png)

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need VBA for this? Select a cell in your data and go to Data (in the ribbon), sort and custom sort. Select the headers you want sorted order of their sort priority. If you must use VBA, record a macro and tweak the code.

Comment: VBA is not a condition. Sorting will sort all the records, where we want to sort all records but within a group, as shown in the snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the conditions for sorting right from your example (otherwise please explain), you can do the following (I reference columns from A to E from your current example):

- add a column F with formula '=Abs(E2)' (example for row 2) to get absolute values
- then sort with columns A, F and C